# Filtering Multiple Columns Containing a Certain Value

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
  A    W     Z     C
  F    W     P     F
  E    P     Y     C
  B    C     B     C
  M    A     V     C
  D    O     X     A
  Y    L     Y     D
  Q    V     R     A
```

I want to filter if multiple columns have a certain value. For instance I want to filter the rows that contain `A`. As a result it should be:

```
 col1  col2  col3  col4
  A    W     Z     C
  M    A     V     C
  D    O     X     A
  Q    V     R     A
```

Since it is just a small representation of a large dataset, I cannot go with

```
df[(df['col1'].str.contains('A')) | (df['col2'].str.contains('A')) | (df['col3'].str.contains('A')) | 
(df['col4'].str.contains('A'))]
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: x == 'A').any(1)]

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    W    Z    C
4    M    A    V    C
5    D    O    X    A
7    Q    V    R    A
```

For multiple cases, you can do like `A`, `B`:

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: x in ['A','B']).any(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @YOLO. Can you explain what the function of `any(1)` is?

Comment: `any(1)` check row-wise if there is any 'A' present, if yes, it returns a `TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, this looks just fine. Just a small question: if this would be a list like `['A','B']` instead of just `A`, how can I make the filter? Because I cannot make an `isin` statement for a string.

Answer (score 4):

We could use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
df[df.stack(dropna=False).str.contains('A').unstack().any(axis=1)]
```

**or better solution suggested by  @Alollz**

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('A').any(level=0)]
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    W    Z    C
4    M    A    V    C
5    D    O    X    A
7    Q    V    R    A
```

**UPDATE**

To check several characters use `join`

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(['A','B'])).any(level=0)]

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    W    Z    C
3    B    C    B    C
4    M    A    V    C
5    D    O    X    A
7    Q    V    R    A
```

Comment: You don't even need the `unstack`. `any` can operate over `Index` levels so: `df.stack().str.contains('A').any(level=0)` gets you the mask.

Comment: @ALollz very nice, i should explore much :) I thought only aggregate functions had levels as param , but didn't consider any

Comment: Yeah, `any`, `sum` and a few others support the `level` argument. I don't think there's any real gain of `df.sum(level=0)` as compared to `df.groupby(level=0).sum()`, other than it being less verbose.

Comment: You are right:) I always forget that I can do this @ALollz

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and `any` along `axis=1`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')).any(1)]
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    W    Z    C
4    M    A    V    C
5    D    O    X    A
7    Q    V    R    A
```

Or:

```
s=df.stack()
s[s.str.contains('A').groupby(level=0).transform('any')].unstack()
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A    W    Z    C
4    M    A    V    C
5    D    O    X    A
7    Q    V    R    A
```